# Set a label on a marker with iOS map links api

Tags: javascript, ios, web, react-native, mapkit

I'm trying to set a label on a map marker using the map links api. According to apple's docs if I use the 'q' param with the 'address' param it will take the 'q' param as a label. But I can't make it to work.

> Blockquote
>   The q parameter can also be used as a label if the location is explicitly defined in the ll or address parameters [docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/iPhoneURLScheme_Reference/MapLinks/MapLinks.html).

This is the url I've tried

```
http://maps.apple.com/?address=San+Jose&q=Blah
```

I want it to say 'Blah' as the marker's label.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I just ran into this issue and submitted a bug report to Apple. According to their docs, the combination of the `q` and `address` parameters should set the marker label to the value of `q`.

In the meantime, you can get this working by using the `ll` parameter:

`http://maps.apple.com/?q=Blah&ll=34.0836834,-118.3468481`

More on the `ll` parameter:

> A comma-separated pair of floating point values that represent latitude and longitude (in that order).
>
> https://developer.apple.com/library/content/featuredarticles/iPhoneURLScheme_Reference/MapLinks/MapLinks.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007899-CH5-SW1

Comment: Thanks @Zach but I don't want to search by the latitude and longitude.. I want to open the maps by an address.